# Printer Detected As USB Composite Device - With Warning

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, printer

My parents have started to have a problem printing from their PC, and naturally as the go-to IT expert, I have been drafted in to have a look!

Before they went on holiday a month ago, it was apparently working fine. On their return last week, they were unable to print. I believe Windows updates were installed on their return.

I have removed the printer, an HP C4400, and uninstalled all related software, then re-installed the software and drivers. When re-adding the printer, the HP install software hangs at "detecting printer". In device manager, I see a "USB Composite Device" appearing, however this shows a yellow warning, with a message stating that the composite device drivers are missing or corrupt.

I have tried adding a different model of printer, with the same result - it appears as a composite USB device, with errors.

I have also tried connecting the printer to another PC, and it installed and worked perfectly.

Any suggestions? How can I repair the composite USB device drivers?

---

**Edit**: The error I am getting is as follows, and appears against the device "USB Composite Device":

> Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

If I press <kbd>F8</kbd> during startup, and select "allow unsigned device drivers" or similar, then the printer works just fine, however this needs to be done every time. Why is Windows blocking the "USB Composite Device" driver from loading?

Comment: Did you install the printer and drivers in the correct order? Most USB connected printers need the printer attached and on before you install the drivers. You need to cancel the "Plug and Play" new USB device found popup so you can install the drivers with "New Printer Wizard" in the Devices and Printers.

Comment: are you able to run System Restore to a recent backup?